# Resources for mathematics terminology in Hindi

Tags: reference-request, terminology, convention

I am trying to add some undergraduate level mathematics in Hindi on wikipedia pages. However, I am running into the lack of terminology.

While most math terminologies exist till the level of high school mathematics, I would like to know if there is any accepted terminology for things like differential manifolds, integrable functions, rings, fields, modules, functional analysis, ramification of prime extensions, etc.

You can help me by pointing out any Hindi textbooks on pure mathematics beyond the school level.